# Can I include a composer.json file in the download package of the dependency-free PHP library project that I maintain?

Tags: php, composer-php, repository

I maintain a small, single-file PHP library that has no dependency. The library is not on Packagist but there is a Composer-type repository on my server with a *packages.json* file and zip files of download packages of various versions of the library. I now want to include a *composer.json* file in the library's download package. Since the library has no dependency, the *composer.json* only declares the repository information of the library itself. My goal is to facilitate Composer-based update of the library by maintainers of projects that use the library. Is this goal achieved without any problem by including the *composer.json* file?

```
{
    "name": "my/myLib",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=4.4"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
         "type": "composer",
         "url": "myUrl"
        },
        {
         "type": "composer",
         "url": "myUrlAlt"
        },
    ]
}
```

*[cross-posted](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/10944) on Composer project site*

Comment: I’m a little confused. You say you have no dependencies, but you are listing repositories. To be honest, if you are willing to make this public, just add it to Packagist and then try using it in another project. Worst case, you delete the whole thing. But it really helps to figure the system out.

Comment: Sorry, I have limited knowledge of Composer. The repository URL in composer.json is for the library itself, and I am wondering about having such a composer.json file in the library's download. I am thinking that someone who downloads the library will be able to update it because the composer.json will tell them where to look for updates.  //  My understanding is that Packagist only takes composer.json with a  Git/Svn/Hg repository and not others like my self-hosted one.

Comment: `packages.json`  is not a file used by Composer

Comment: For 'composer' type of repositories, packages.json file at the repository URL lists the downloadable packages (different versions, etc.) in the repository. https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, this is not unusual case.

PHPStan does that: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/blob/1.8.1/composer.json